# How to convert spring boot application to a Dynamic web project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

After converting my spring-boot application to a dynamic web project by changing 'Project Facets', all java classes show error as they can't see the relevant libs.
How to convert my app to a dynamic web project?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop the Spring boot application, use Eclipse STS better.

Try to import the project in Eclipse STS, but it is a maven project.

[Eclipse STS download](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all)

Some links:

[very-basic-web-application-with-spring-mvc-spring-boot-and-eclipse-sts](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/18/very-basic-web-application-with-spring-mvc-spring-boot-and-eclipse-sts)

[Working a Getting Started guide with STS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts)